# Initiate deep linking from browser

Tags: browser

I wanted to test [deep links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking) on my phone. According to [WhatsApp site](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012), tapping `whatsapp://send?text=<text>` link on browser should launch WhatsApp app. I have the WhatsApp app installed, but when I went to the browser and typed `whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!` (which is a deep link that opens WhatsApp to send a "hello world" message), I get a Google Search instead of opening WhatsApp.

I tried it with the Twitter and FB deep links and I get the same.
I even tried it on an Android emulator, but still the same.

What is wrong? Is there any configuration or permission to be given or what?

PS: my phone has Android 4.1.2 and the emulator has Android 5.0.1.

Comment: mobile deep linking usually uses a custom URI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking
you can check them out here : http://www.gotschemes.com/search/?app_id=2541 – it's mentioned in the whatsapp website https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/ru/android/28000012

Comment: Is it the same with all the browsers?

Comment: @MANI I tried it in Android default browser and Google chrome

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189172/google-chrome-does-not-open-application-on-deep-link-on-android